# How to move a VOB to new server(CentOS) with New/Different VOB name

Tags: centos7, clearcase

I have two CentOS Clearcase VOB Severs, I need to move all the VOBs to new CentOS server. With the below commands I can able to move the VOBs successfully. However couple of VOBs I need to move to new server with New name.

**CentOS VOB Old Server:-**

```
1. Lock the vob
2. Unregister the vob
3. Remove the vob tag
4. cleartool reformatvob -dump -force -host oldcentos-host -hpath hpath
5. Tar and copy using scp commad.
```

**CentOS VOB New Server:-**

```
1. cleartool reformatvob -load -host newcentos-host -hpath hpath
2. Register the vob
3. Make tag
4. Unlock the vob
```

I have tried below.

```
1.  Untarred the vob storage folder.
2.  Renamed the vob storage folder
3.  cleartool reformatvob -load -host newcentos-host -hpath hpath (with new VOB name path)
4.  cleartool register -vob –replace (New vob name storage location)
5.  Make tag -vob -tag new-tag-name (failing) saying VOB with tag already existing.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best, once you have successfully migrated the new Vob, to rename its existing imported tag.

> To completely rename a ClearCase VOB (replicated or non-replicated) or View requires that both the storage and the tag be renamed.

Follow the process mentioned [in that page](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/renaming-clearcase-vob-or-view) (again, once the Vob is migrated)

It will involve unmounting the vob, [kill the vob server](http://www-1.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?&rs=984&uid=swg21148639), remove the vob tag, Remove the ClearCase registry entry, rename the vob storage, register and retag.

```
cleartool umount \<VOB-tag> # on clients
albd_list [-s <vob_or_view_storage>] 
kill -9 #theVobProcess
cleartool rmtag -vob -all \<VOB-tag>
cleartool unregister -vob <VOB-storage-pname>.vbs
mv <old-VOB-storage> <new-VOB-storage>.vbs
cleartool register -vob <new-VOB-storage>.vbs
cleartool mktag -vob -public -tag \<new-VOB-tag> <new-VOB-storage>.vbs
cleartool mount <new-VOB-tag> # on all clients to remount the VOB
```